# How to pass msExchArchiveGUID to IMAPISession:OpenMsgStore to access Archive mailbox

Tags: outlook, office365, mapi, outlook-2013

I am trying to access user's mailbox as well as archive mailbox using Outlook MAPI. Outlook version is 2013. User's mailbox and archive both are in O365 (Exchange Online)
I am able to access users mailbox. However, access to users archive mailbox fails.
I have user's email address and Archive GUID of the archive mailstore.
Can someone please help me understand how to pass Archive GUID of user's mailbox to IMAPISession:OpenMsgStore.

Thanks,
Pranay

Answer (score 0):

You will need to retrieve the legacy DN and server information from the autodiscover XML (Type == Archive), then construct the store entry id using IExchangeManageStore::CreateStoreEntryID in the same fashion as when opening a delegate mailbox.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko.
I am able to find out Legacy DN and Server name using AutoDiscover XML. Legacy DN contains archive guid appended at the end ("/guid=...").
CreateStoreEntryID expects server name and mailbox name as parameters.
I have 2 more questions: 
1. Do I need to pass server name as I obtained from Autodiscover XML and LegacyDN as mailbox name without any modifications?

Comment: Legacy DN contains archive guid. Do I need to massage the LegacyDN string before passing it to CreateStoreID ?
Thanks !

Comment: No, you just need to add the usual "/cn=Microsoft Private MDB" suffix to the store DN. This is not any different from opening a delegate store.

Comment: Again thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko but I am still struggling.
I retrieved AlternateMailboxes settings using EWS.
This gives me –
Server: <mailbox_archive_guid>@xyz.onmicrosoft.com
LegacyDN: /o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHFxxSPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=<x-y-z>@abc.onmicrosoft.com/cn=Microsoft Private MDB
I pass server value (as mentioned above) as “ServerDN” parameter whereas LegecyDN value is passed as mailboxDN.
CreateStoreEntryID fails with these parameters.
Can you please let me know if this is the correct way to call CreateStoreEntryID..

Comment: That sounds right. Compare your store entry id with what Outlook uses when you open the same mailbox as a delegate store  You can see the store entry id in OutlookSpy - click IMsgStore, select PR_ENTRYID (or PR_STORE_ENTRYID) and click "..." button next to the Value edit box.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko. I am able to Create EntryID using CreateStoreEntryID. 
However, OpenMsgStore fails with this EntryID. The strange thing I noticed here is if I follow following steps, OpenMsgStore works fine.
1.Open the same profile in Outlook (Outlook 2013 SP1), let Outlook load the profile and then close Outlook
2.Execute the same code without any change
Everything works fine. OpenMsgStore returns success. 
I did this on multiple machines and got same results. OpenMsgStore returns success after I open profile in Outlook. Any idea what magic Outlook is doing here?
Thanks,
Pranay

Comment: What is the error? Did you compare your store id with what Outlook uses?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. I verified the store id and entry id in Outlook using OutlookSpy. They are same. I believe store/Entry ID are correct else it would have failed each time but that is not the case. 
OpenMsgStore works fine while accessing the user’s mailbox but it fails while accessing archive mailbox before opening profile in Outlook. I am not  able to understand why OpenMsgStore fails initially and then works each time once the profile is opened in Outlook.
Also, I verified this behaviour against Exchange 2013 On premise and OpenMsgStore works fine. Issue is with only O365 archive mailbox.

Comment: I don't know. You might want to open a support case with MS.